# asymptotic behavior of the series $f(t) = \sum_{n\geq 1 } \cos(n t )/\sqrt{n}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-series

This is a periodic function of $t$.

At $t = 2m \pi $, it diverges. But for other values, we know by the Abel criterion that it converges.

The problem is, what is the asymptotic behavior of $f$ as $t\rightarrow 0^+ $?

As a similar question, how about the function

$$g (t ) = \sum_{n\geq 1 } \sin (nt) /\sqrt{n} $$

It should have a jump at $t = 0 $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can analyze $$g(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2} e^{-nt},\qquad \Re(t) \ge 0, t \not \in 2i \pi \mathbb{Z}$$ from its Mellin transform $$G(s)=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}g(t)dt=\Gamma(s) \zeta(s+1/2)$$ obtaining that for $t \in (0,1)$  $$g(t)  = 
\frac{1}{2i\pi } \int_{1-i\infty}^{1+i\infty} G(s) t^{-s}ds=\sum Res(G(s) t^{-s})=\Gamma(1/2) t^{-1/2}+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \zeta(1/2-k) t^k $$
which stays true for $|t|< 1,\Re(t) \ge 0$ by analytic continuation, as well as for $|t|< 2\pi,\Re(t) \ge 0$ by the decay property of $\frac{\zeta(1/2-k)}{k!}$ found from the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$

Comment: (+1), I obtained the asymptotics $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2t}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^{s^2}-1}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}s+o(1)$ as $t \to 0^+$. Now it makes sense as to why I get this one, as well as an integral representation of $\zeta(1/2)$ as well :)

Comment: @SangchulLee You got it for $g(t)$, from Abel summation formula ? Working on $g(it)$ should be harder ?

Comment: I began by writing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-1/2}\cos(nt)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-ns^2}\cos(nt)\,\mathrm{d}s$. Not a fancy way to begin with compared to your elegant and systematic approach, but it was not entirely useless as I could extract first two leading terms out of it...

Comment: it is a high-tech for me. Is there any good reference on Mellin transform and its application?

Comment: @S.Kohn The Mellin transform is the same as the Laplace/Fourier transform (with $t = e^{-u}$). Then I used the residue theorem and the decay of $G(s)$ on vertical lines and its decay as $\Re(s) \to -\infty$ which needs a lot of properties of $\Gamma(s),\zeta(s)$. One of the main property of is that the inverse MT $\frac{1}{2i\pi } \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} G(s) t^{-s}ds$ doesn't depend on $\sigma$ in the strip of convergence, so the point is to shift $\sigma$ to the left as much as possible, taking in account the encountered poles at $s \in 1/2 \cup \mathbb{Z}_{\le 0}$

Comment: To reduce the integral to a sum over the residues, you have the close the contour. How do you know that the added part's contribution is zero?

Comment: @S.Kohn This is what I meant with the last sentence in my answer : it follows from the functional equation and the behavior of $\Gamma(s/2)$.